# Python: keeping count (counter) in my function and printing the total outside my function

Tags: python

I'm taking a python course and stuck on a task. I need to call my function twice, print if it is correct or incorrect then print the total number of correct inputs. Everything seems to work fine except for the total number of correct inputs.

My while loop goes through my function twice like it should and tells the user if they entered a correct or incorrect bone. I just can't seem to figure out how to print the total number of correct inputs after the loop is done. Any suggestions would be appreciated. thanks.

Here is my code:

```
foot_bones = ["calcaneus", "talus", "cuboid", "navicular", "lateral cuneiform", "intermediate cuneiform", "medial cuneiform"]

correct_bones = 0

def f_bones(footbone, foot_bones):
    correct_bones = 0
    for bones in foot_bones:
        if bones.lower() == footbone.lower():
            correct_bones += bones.lower().count(bones)
            return "correct"
        else:
            pass
    return "incorrect"

count = 1

while count < 3:
    count += int(count)
    p_bone = input("Enter a foot bone: ")
    print(p_bone, "is", f_bones(p_bone,foot_bones))
print("Total # of bones identified: ", correct_bones)
```

My output:

```
Enter a foot bone: talus

talus is correct

Enter a foot bone: cuboid

cuboid is correct

Total # of bones identified:  0
```

Comment: That's because you don't `return correct_bones`. So the `print` statement takes the global value of `correct_bones` which is `0`. The changes in `correct_bones` inside the function are local.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `correct_bones` 2 times, once before `def f_bones():` and once inside the function. Then later after the `while()` you print the wrong `correct_bones`. You need to change the return value from the strings of `"correct"`, and `"incorrect"` to 0 and 1 or whatever number you like. Then when you call the `f_bone` function you need to set it to something so `fBone = f_bone(p_bone,foot_bones)`, then you can print out `fBone` and it will hold the value you desire.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I'll try your suggestion's as well.  I also found 1 other way that made it work (not sure if it's ideal).  in my function, add "global" to correct_bones. "global correct_bones".

Comment: that can work as well, but beware it could lead to extra confusion. Normally it is not smart to name global and local things the same thing. it becomes easily confusing for you, others and especially those grading you.